# Toggle circuit with 1 x NAND, OR, and NOT gates?

Tags: digital-logic

I am sure there is a more specific name than "toggle circuit".

I am simplifying a schematic. To do so I have replaced a larger circuit with one much smaller, but in doing so, I have lost the 74*74 flip-flop used in a "toggle circuit" as seen below:

[image: existing circuit]

---

I have three spare gates I can use to attempt to re-implement something similar.

- 3-input NAND
- 2-input OR
- inverter

Diodes, NPN transistors, and passives are allowed too.

---

Any idea on a circuit that would operate similarly? (Toggle an output whenever 'A' goes high).

As I understand the existing circuit correctly, it acts as a 1/2 clock divider.

I imagine I could simply use two inverters to perform the same function as the flip-flop circuit, except it would switch twice as fast, as it won't be divided by two anymore.

Comment: the 'more specific name' is a T flip-flop.

Comment: And no, you can't create an edge-triggered function with just those gates.

Comment: That's "a D-Type flip-flop configured in Toggle mode". It's not a T-Type flip-flop. A T-Type flip flop has two inputs, a clk input and a control input. When its control input is asserted, the input clock signal appears divided by two at the output. When the control input is dissaserted, the output freezes in its last state. Therefore a T-type flip-flop would be as above but the feedback would be via an X-Or gate. Alternatively a JK flip-flop could be used with its J & K inputs tied together and used as the control input.

Comment: You have effectively two inverters. (I think the "OR" isn't useful here.) Are you willing to consider adding 6 resistors, 2 diodes, and 2 tiny caps? Also, is your NAND and inverter both of the HC variety? Or HCU?

Comment: @jonk. Yes I can add those parts. They'll all be whatever is cheapest at the time in DIP, TTL-compatible, and faster than HC. So it'll be F, ACT, or AHCT.

Comment: @Mono I may have to know which, to set the resistor values. I'm thinking of three resistors in 'star' formation; one at the output of each inverter, the other two splitting the supply rail. Trimmed close enough to the input thresholds (but far enough away, considering noise and part variations) so that the small caps can pull one way or another and flip their combined state. (The diodes are also needed.) Looks like I'll have to go read about all three families to work out thresholds and see if one-size-fits-all is even possible.

Comment: @jonk it'll almost certainly be SN74AHCT04N at this stage; I don't think it'll change. Can just use two inverters from that; I'll replace another inverter elsewhere with the NAND to make things simpler.

Comment: @Mono Sounds like a good idea, allowing two free identical devices rather than having to mix and match. I don't know if my idea will work yet. I just have a direction to head in. I'll let you know.

Comment: @Mono Ah. Looking at the AHCT, it appears that most of the gates are designed for very fast rise and fall times (under \$50\:\text{ns}\$.) You'll need Schmitt triggers, I think, for the idea I had. Any chance you might accept the idea of using [74AHCT14](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahct14.pdf) devices?

Comment: @jonk even the slowest 74-series logic gates seem faster than 50ns. You'd probably have to go to 4000-series to get some slow gates. I can most likely switch to 74HCT which are slower, but not 50ns slow. The other inverters in the package are being used in address decoding circuits. I'll need to study if the hysteresis of 74AHCT14 will negatively affect these circuits.

Comment: @Mono I don't think Schmitt triggers will be problematic. They appear to accept fast inputs, too. It's just that they also accept slow ones. (So I think, anyway.) Let me know. (The non-Schmitt trigger gates seem to ***require*** fast transitions to meet specs. But maybe I'm reading that wrong, too.)

Comment: @jonk that seems to be what I read too. Regular inputs need fast slew rates. But there must be a reason 74*04 exists; 74*14 can't replace it in all scenarios. I imagine it will work fine for my purpose, but I will research more.

Comment: @Mono Here is the diagram from [AHCT14 transfer characteristics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QerXm.png). This is what I find from [page 20 from TI on this topic](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ug/scla013d/scla013d.pdf).

Comment: @Mono Okay. Well, it seems to "simulate" okay. I had to add another two resistors, though. Are you still up for the concept? I can provide an LTspice schematic and yes, I did actually do some mathematics to select values. I can't actually test this with real parts, though. And I haven't done any monte carlo variations to validate it's behavior over part and temperature variations. I'm using "ideal" parts. But perhaps it's enough for you to consider. Let me know if you are still interested in seeing something.

Comment: @jonk sure thing I can give it a try with real parts. Show me a schematic. I haven't used LTspice. I have used Multisim a little bit for simulation.

Comment: @Mono Well, LTspice doesn't have 74AHCT14 device models. What it has are behavioral Schmitt trigger inverters where I have to specify the thresholds. It is so idealized that I have to add one extra capacitor so that one inverter starts after the other. If I don't, it sits there busily trying to analyze two identical inverters with identical timing. So a little help is needed. Real parts won't have that problem.

Comment: @Mono Okay. I added the crazy thought below. Yeah, it's insane. But you pretty much stuck me with two inverters to use. Another way to do it would be to just completely forget about the inverters and just use two BJTs, instead. Probably would still work fine. (But since you already have the inverters, why add two BJTs?) Sorry the darned thing is so complicated. But there it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following transfer characteristics chart suggests a center voltage of \$1.3\:\text{V}\$, with \$\pm 300\:\text{mV}\$ hysteresis. The chart was taken from page 13 of TI's [AHC/AHCT Designer’s Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/scla013d/scla013d.pdf).

[image]

So I designed the three resistors, \$R_1\$, \$R_3\$ and \$R_5\$, so that their shared node would be at \$800\:\text{mV}\$ if the previous inverter output was **LO** and at \$1.8\:\text{V}\$ if the previous inverter output was **HI**. Plugging in \$33\:\text{k}\Omega\$ as the output resistor, this meant the other two should be \$41.25\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$10.31\:\text{k}\Omega\$. I selected nearby standard values, instead. Same calculations go for \$R_2\$, \$R_4\$ and \$R_6\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feECeJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ are something you will need to adjust. I've selected approximate values that work with idealized behavioral inverters in LTspice. But reality is another thing and you may need to adjust their magnitude. Both should be the same value, though. (\$R_7\$ and \$R_8\$ are probably just fine as they are. But feel free to try something different.) I'm assuming your pulse edge is less than \$10\:\mu\text{s}\$ rise time. If not, you may need larger values for the capacitors.

You can pick off your output from either inverter, of course.

If you have any trouble in simulation you can just slap a \$100\:\text{pF}\$ capacitor to ground onto the input node of either inverter, just to slow things down for one of them -- enough to let the simulator find a starting point. (Since I was using idealized inverters in LTspice, I needed one of those.) Actual parts will vary enough and will quickly find a starting point on their own. But if you want a known power-up value, then that's a way to achieve that, too.

Answer (score 1):

A you say you allow diodes and transistors, why not place a 5pin SC70 package with a single D register from Texas Instruments. It uses 2.2x2.4 mm.

I think these are called 'tiny gates' as they are for exact the situation you are in: you need one/two more gates to finish the circuit.

[This](http://www.ti.com/logic-circuit/flip-flop-latch-register/d-type-flip-flop/products.html#p848=1;1) is the search page for 1 bit registers.

Comment: Thanks. That would do it if I was going SMT, but the design will be THT for aesthetic reasons (it's vintage computer stuff).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.

Using your available components, you can make a weird variant of an SR flip-flop (opposite polarities on the inputs), but you need another level of circuitry to get edge activation.